# How to sum 24 observations at a time in R?

Tags: r

I have this dataset :
[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3V3S.jpg)

I would like to get a new vector (rendimenti.2) that contains the sum of 24 observations at a time. The dataset contains 35232 observations, so the new vector will have 35232: 24 = 1468 observations, how to do in R?

Comment: Simple approach: add a grouping column `df$group = (1:nrow(df) - 1) %/% 24` and then pick your favorite answer from the FAQ on [How to sum data by group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1660124/903061). There  may be a smarter way to create the groups, depending on the meaning of your data.

Answer (score 0):

It's two parts: how to divide your data into groups of 24, and how to calculate the sums by groups. Here is one way:

```
tapply(dataset$rendimenti, trunc(0:35231/24), sum)
```

`aggregate` is another answer to the second part of the question. And of course, `sapply` and `dplyr::summarise` can do it as well.

For the first sub-question, you can use `%/%` as in Gregor's comment to the OP, or `rep` (say, `rep(1:(35232/24), length.out=35232, each=24)`).